# Clojure: From Prismatic Schema nested data structure to SQL Tables

Tags: sql, types, clojure, database-schema

I would like to convert a Prismatic Schema nested specs to flat SQL tables creation where when adding lines, schema gets validated.

```
(defn max-length [l] (s/pred (fn [x] (<= (count x) l))))
(defn min-length [l] (s/pred (fn [x] (>= (count x) l))))
(defn length     [l] (s/pred (fn [x] (= (count x) l))))
(defn matches    [r] (s/pred (fn [s] (re-matches r s))))

(defn linked-to-many [& keys] ???)
(defn schema->tables [coll]   ???)
(defn add-line       [t coll] ???)

(def schema 
  {:ideas {:id s/Uuid                               ; not sure about this type
           :title (s/both s/String (max-length 50))
           :tags (linked-to-many :tags :id)         ; a list of tag ids
           :votes (linked-to-many :users :id)       ; a list of user ids
           (s/optional :desc) (s/both s/String (max-length 300))} 
   :users {:id s/Uuid
           :f-name (s/both s/String (min-length 2))
           :l-name (s/both s/String (min-length 2))
           :zip (s/both s/Int (length 5))
           :email (s/both (min-length 5) (matches #".*@.*"))
           (s/optional :no-spam) s/Bool}
   :tags {:id 
          :name (s/both s/String (max-length 15))
          :related (linked-to-many :tags :id) }     ; similar tag ids

(schema->tables schema)
;=> sql tables...

(add-line :tags {:name "Too long tag name which will trigger prismatic error"
                 :related [1 23 8]}) 
;=> prismatic validation error
```

I suppose it should create 6 SQL tables adding :votes, :tags-ideas and :tags-tags tables...

How can I achieve this? 
Are there any libraries that can help me with this project? 
(Maybe I could use something like [aggregate](https://github.com/friemen/aggregate)?)